# What is the point of MasterLocationFormats in a razor view engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewengine

If I understand correctly it is intended to specify which locations are searched in order to locate the master `_Layout.cshtml` file.

However my `_ViewStart.cshtml` file requires a full path, e.g. `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`.  This means that any location(s) specified in `MasterLocationFormats` are totally ignored.

***My Questions Are:***

- Why bother including `MasterLocationForamts[]` in the first place?
- Is there another use for `MasterLocationFormats[]` that I'm missing?
- Is there a way to make `_ViewStart.cshtml` search in the locations
  specified in `MasterLocationFormats[]`?

I have tried using a relative path like `_Layout.cshtml` in `_ViewStart.cshtml` but that didn't  work)

I've googled around this and while it must be explained somewhere, I am unable to find it. I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882794/why-is-a-full-path-to-layout-required-in-viewstart-file-when-locations-are-speci) a while back and though I appreciate the person answering, it didn't really address the crux of my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have an answer, sort of.

I had mistakenly thought that MasterPages = Layout.chtml. Not true.

They're a similar concept but only used by the `WebFormsViewEngine`, not the `RazorViewEngine`.

As further explanation, I will quote heavily from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16049543/1778169):

> Starting with MVC3, the razor view engine was introduced. Razor
>   doesn't allow you to use master pages.
>
> MVC3 and 4 have another view engine called the WebForms view engine
>   [that uses] master pages.
>
> Master pages allow you to define content place holders, while razor
>   allows you to define sections. Master pages render the page outside
>   in, meaning first the master page, then the content place holders.
>   Razor is I believe recursive and starts with the innermost section and
>   works it's way back out.

So, it appears that the concept of master pages is not valid when using razor.

But my question still stands:

***Why are`MasterLocationFormats` even included in the `RazorViewEngine`?***

Please post an answer if you know - I will mark that as the correct one.