# JS library for extending/inheriting HTML templates

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I need a way to inherit one HTML template(file) from another. The way I see it: `parent.html`:

```html
<h1><!-- header --></h1>

<div class="container">
  <!-- container -->
</div>
```

`child.html`:

```html
<!-- extends: ./parent.html -->

<!-- <header> -->
Child Page
<!-- </header> -->

<!-- <content> -->
<span>Content</span>
<!-- </content> -->
```

Total duplicate of [master page feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322108/mvc-layout-vs-mvc-master-page) available in ASP .NET MVC or [layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield) of RoR.

Can anyone point me to a library that does something similar? (I going to use it as a loader for webpack, so if there is already a loader for this it would be perfect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend Nunjucks from Mozilla. You can use it via NPM or browser, also it is compiled.

https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#template-inheritance